# c++ templates more than one prototype

Tags: c++, templates

I have a relatively complex template with a lot of arguments (most of them with default values). For example:

```
template <typename I,
          typename S = BasicS<I>,
          typename C = BasicC<I>,
          typename E = BasicE<I> >
class Foo ...
```

Unfortunately whatever order of the arguments I choose there are always cases where you may want to change only the last one.

How I could create more prototypes for the same template, say

```
template <typename I,
          typename E>
class Foo1 : Foo<I, BasicS<I>, BasicC<I>, E >
{
    ... redefine the constructors
};
```

but without inheritance to avoid the need of redefining the constructors

Comment: You can use inheriting constructors to avoid the need of redefining them (`using Base::Base`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (based on your comments) that you can't use C++11, you can get close with using a nested typedef:

```
template <typename I, typename E>
struct Foo1 {
  typedef Foo<I, BasicS<I>, BasicC<I>, E> type;
};

template <typename I, typename C>
struct Foo2 {
  typedef Foo<I, BasicS<I>, C> type;
};
```

Which would then be used like this:

```
Foo1<MyI, MyE>::type myFoo;
```

Of course, you can also rename the original `Foo` to `GenericFoo` or something and provide a `Foo` struct with a typedef to it, so that you offer a consistent interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that with [C++11's template aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Alias_templates):

```
template <typename I, typename E>
using Foo1 = Foo<I, BasicS<I>, BasicC<I>, E>;
```

Comment: ... and there is no way without c++11 support?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can accept different names, you can use a `using` alias:

```
template <typename I, typename E>
using Foo1 = Foo<I, BasicS<I>, BasicC<I>, E>;
```